# ElementFinder error when I do getText in a console.log in protractor

Tags: protractor

Im trying to do a `element.all` like this

```
element.all(by.className('col-md-4 ng-scope')).all(by.className('chart-small-titles dashboard-alignment ng-binding')).then(function(items) {
           console.log(items[1].getText());
});
```

This code return this:

```
ElementFinder {
  browser_:
   ProtractorBrowser {
     controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     setFileDetector: [Function],
     getExecutor: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
```

and more lines of code like this.

I am doing something wrong? Maybe I am using wrong the .all function, i don't know.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what happens when you chain elementFinderArrays in this way, it appears both those `.all` statements could be combined without changing the behavior. Other than that `getText` returns a promise which needs to be resolved with a .then

Comment: Hi @DublinDev i wanted to find a parent, but  i don't need fisr `.all`. Also, i needed the `.then` like you told me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There may be different things that go wrong. Try this

```
element.all(by.className('col-md-4 ng-scope')).all(by.className('chart-small-titles dashboard-alignment ng-binding')).then(function(items) {
    items.get(1).getText().then(
        function (text) {
            console.log(text);
        })
    )
});
```